# Is igraph R package more perfect than python-igraph?

Tags: igraph

I try to use igraph package transferring from R to python. But I have one question. For instance, I want to use the graph.bfs function. In R, this function has many parameters. (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/graph.bfs)
But in python-igraph, I only find the function bfs. (http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#bfs)

Did I miss the similar function in python-igraph or is igraph R package more perfect than python-igraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While they are based on the same C library, the Python and R wrappers are somewhat different, so expect to have some differences. I would not say either of them is better or worse, they are just slightly different.

If there is a feature that is implemented in one language, but not in the other, then you can open an issue at the igraph issue tracker at https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues and request it.

Comment: @Gabor Csardi,  I am also unable to find function for getting cluster memebership in igraph python, but its present in R